# Interfaces do not come up automatically when ethernet is plugged in, 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, sbc

I have a minimal installation of 16.04 on a singleboard computer, the network interfaces are configured through the interfaces file (network manager is not installed).

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 10.0.0.31

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 10.42.0.31
```

The virtual interfaces are to handle several potential connection scenarios depending on where the SBC is. I've successfully used this configuration on similar machine running 14.04 for more than a year. Connecting directly to my laptop which is set to "share connection" and gives out IP's 10.42.0.X, the first dhcp connection works but none of the others seem to get configured.

I tried a simpler configuration then:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.31
```

The behavior is stranger. Attempting to connect from my laptop via a direct ethernet connection (static IP on both sides now, 10.0.0.50 on the laptop). When I plug the cable in, I cannot ping the SBC from laptop.

```
From 10.0.0.50 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I ping any IP 10.0.0.X from the SBC then the laptop suddenly can find/ping/ssh into the SBC.

- Why aren't the virtual interfaces configured with the first setup?
- Why can't my laptop find the SBC with the static configuration?
- Are these related problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have 2 or 3 ethernet devices? You have both dhcp and static configured at the same time. You also don't specify the gateway or the mask.

Comment: The eth0:X are virtual interfaces to the same physical device. In all of the static configurations there is no gateway since it is a direct connection between the two machines both of which are configured with static IPs. I've tried messing with the masks to no effect.

Comment: In your simpler configuration, try adding `gateway 10.0.0.1` and `mask 255.255.255.0`. Do the same on the laptop. See what happens.

Comment: No change in behavior.

Comment: Hopefully a network expert will jump in and assist.